# CLASSPATH url format

Tags: url, classpath

i'm searching for a path for some resource which is in CLASSPATH. I'm using the method from ClassLoader `getResource(String name)` and i get `URL`. From this URL i get a path with method `getPath()`. The format of that depends on that whether the resorce is in JAR or not. If the resource is in JAR then i get `file:/C:/path/lib.jar!/resourceName.resource`. If the resource is not in JAR then i get `/C:/path/resourceName.resource`.

My question is are these path OS independent? When i invoke this code on UNIX JVM do i get this same path format?

Kind regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: The filename is actually OS independent. Java can handle this fine.
Second: Remember your jar might be on the classpath but must not be a file!

You can just use `getResourceAsStream(name)` so you don't have to care about this at all.